# Count number of spaces, and split at the last one

Tags: powershell, count, powershell-2.0

I have a string simliar to:

```
c:/folder name/somewhere/application.exe instanceName
```

(n.b. the space in "folder name" is intentional) I need a way to split this into:

```
[0]c:/folder name/somewhere/application.exe
[1]instanceName
```

I was going to use `split-path`, but apparently there is a bug in powershell v2 that stops me doing this:

```
Split-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '
```

So, I figured if I count how many spaces there are, and then simply use `-split()` to split it at the last space.
But, I can't see how to count the number of spaces. 
I've found lots of examples that talk about using regex to count complex strings, but I just want to count spaces!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tonnes of ways to do this I imagine but to use your split idea you could do the following.

```
$split = "c:/folder name/somewhere/application.exe instanceName".Split(" ")
$path =  $split[0..($split.count -2)] -Join " "
$instance = $split[-1]
```

Split the sting by spaces. The number of spaces is represented by the count of strings in the array `$split`. We join all the strings in the array accept the last intp `$path` then we take the last entry and assign it to `$instance`

You could also use `.substring` and `.lastindexof`

```
$string = "c:/folder name/somewhere/application.exe instanceName"
$index = $string.LastIndexOf(" ")
$string.Substring(0,$index)
$string.Substring($index + 1)
```

I can't see a way to split this directly into an array at this time but outputing as an array would not be a big deal.

```
$path, $instance
```

or

```
$array = @($path,$instance)
```

Comment: cheers, all of those work really well. However it turns out I have other problems (my text string isn't a string- even after |out-string). But cheers, for your response, it was very useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression for this:

```powershell
$s = "c:/folder name/somewhere/application.exe instanceName"
$s -match '(.*) (.*)$'
$matches[1]
$matches[2]
```

The special variable `$matches` is populated if the `-match` operation is true.

`$matches[0]` contains the original string, and other indexes will exist for the number of groups (patterns in parenthesis) in the regex. In this case: `(.*) (.*)$` we have two groups.