# Splitting a custom object into useable strings

Tags: object, powershell, split, powershell-2.0

I have an issue that I have created a custom object, and now I need to pull out the contents to work on.

```
$cfg_data = @(
"c:/Folder name/Somewhere/Application.exe instanceName,1"
) 

$objHere = @()

FOREACH($a in $cfg_data)
{
    $dataSplit = $a -split"(,)"
    $AppN = $dataSplit[0]
    $AppD = $dataSplit[2]

    $objHere += New-Object PSObject -property @{appItem = "$AppN";appData = "$AppD";}         
}

FOREACH($a in $objHere)
{
    $item = $a | select-object -property appItem | out-string //converts to a string?

    $itemLow = $item.ToLower() #make string lower case?

}
```

But I now need to split the 'string' into two parts ([cheers to the guys for helping here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27191281/count-number-of-spaces-and-split-at-the-last-one/27191710#27191710)) e.g.

```
$ad = "c:/folder name/somewhere/application.exe"
$i = "instanceName"
```

And then further split the first string into

```
$p1 = "c:/folder name/somewhere"
$p2 = "application.exe"
```

But when I try to split these I run into problems
    write-host "ITEM: "+$item

results in:

```
AppCmd
-------
c:/Folder name/Somewhere/Application.exe instanceName
```

and

```
write-host "itemLow: "+$itemLow
```

results in:

```
AppCmd
-------
c:/folder name/somewhere/application.exe instanceName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am looking into your other issues but the first I see is how you are extracting the `appitem` from `$a`.

```
$item = $a | select-object -property appItem | out-string
```

The two things you could be doing instead are

```
$item = $a | select-object -ExpandProperty appItem
```

or

```
$item = $a.appItem
```

You need to break the string out of the object. Using `-expandproperty` or `.PROPERTYNAME` will accomplish it. Else what you have is an object with only one property which is what your `select-Object` statement would return.

You code is incomplete as to what you do after your sample, even though I think it's easy to infer it.

Comment: cheers for that, changing from `property` to `ExpandProperty` fixed the issue. Regarding the incomplete code, my apolgies I'm converting an old script (based on adding to a text string), and thought this was a good time to start using objects instead of an ever longer text string. It hasn't been as straightforward as I'd hoped. But thanks to everyone on this site, I'm getting there (and learning an awful lot in the process).